# Spring security Saml - Time difference between SP and IDP

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0

I am looking for a way to increase the expiration time of my saml messages. I use Spring Security with SAML 1.0.0-RC2.

At this moment, if the servers** time are too different, e.g. 5 minutes, I got following error:

```
HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed:Error validating SAML message: SAML response is not valid; nested exception is org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: SAML response is not valid
```

I want to set the expiration time to 10 minutes, to prevent those errors. I have been looking at the documentation, but I don't understand how to change the expiration time. If I look at the [Configuration authentication object](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-sso.html#configuration-authentication-object) section, one would be able to change the expiration time but I fail to grasp the idea.

Could somebody help me out?

** My server (SP) and server of the customer (IDP, most likely a server with ADFS installed).

Comment: Other error messages you'll get that indicate a responseSkew / time mismatch between SP and IdP are: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response issue time is either too old or with date in the future, skew 60, time 2015-08-27T12:40:28.284Z, or Response issue time in LogoutResponse is either too old or with date in the future.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After Stefan's anwser, I knew where to look! Actually the docs did describe this thing, I just didn't pick it up: [10.3 Validity intervals](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-advanced.html#time-interval). Cheers to Stefan for pointing out the responseSkew property!

Just add the property responseSkew to the WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl and SingleLogoutProfileImpl beans:

```
<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl">
    <property name="responseSkew" value="600"/> <!-- 10 minutes -->
</bean>

<bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl">
    <property name="responseSkew" value="600"/> <!-- 10 minutes -->
</bean>
```

Comment: @jacob, I am using grails where even after I have specified responseSkew as 60000  I am still getting this error! Any help ??? In grails I don't have bean declaration so everything is wired from config file. so the is set fine.. but still I am getting same exception

Comment: @artapart: Sorry I never have worked with Grails in my live, so I don't know. Just ask this as a new stackoverflow question, so the Grails community can help you with this!

Comment: Did you also have to disable CSRF ?

`<security:csrf disabled="true"/>`

Comment: No, you could keep your current CSRF settings. No need to change that!

Comment: @JacobvanLingen Hi, I am facing the same issue. When trying the bean you provided, I got the an error:  `Error creating bean with name 'webSSOprofileConsumer'. No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager' available`. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the allowed time differance is hard coded.

[See this source file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/883386b7fec3c0315e28744a395c2e7ae18a07a3/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/websso/AbstractProfileBase.java) look at the constant responseSkew. The default is 60 sec.

I think your best option here is to try to set the same time on the servers.

Comment: Thank you very much, you did give me a direction to search the problem. But the value is not hardcode, it's defaulted at 60 seconds!

Comment: Correct, sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

I know, the answer has been chosen, but I am sharing resolution which I have found for anyone working with Grails 3, spring security core, SAML 2.0.

I had to set`maxAssertionTime` value along with `responseSkew` for WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl to be able to get the response back from the IDP.