# How to set responseSkew property value in WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to integrate SAML OKTA in a spring boot application. I need to use the the following bean setup in spring boot:

Can any one please help me setting the responseSkew property in webSSOprofileConsumer bean in Spring boot.I just need an equivalent spring injection technique of the xml configuration that I mentioned above in annotation based spring boot injection.

I have already gone through the link :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-advanced.html

There it is mentioned about setting  responseSkew but it is not mentioned how to do it in java based annotated configuration in a spring boot application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647925/spring-security-saml-time-difference-between-sp-and-idp/25661326

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a child class of AbstractProfileBase (e.g. WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl) you simply can use its setter:

setResponseSkew(int responseSkew)

For xml configuration of spring boot I dunno how to achieve this because I never got used to it.